# AppDomain.ActivationContext is NULL

Tags: c#, appdomain, activation-context-api

I have created an AppDomain in my application. Below is the code I have used

```
AppDomainSetup domaininfo = new AppDomainSetup();
domaininfo.ApplicationBase = "C:\\";
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain", null, domaininfo);
ActivationContext context = domain.ActivationContext;
```

But the `ActivationContext` is `null` in above snippet. Can anyone help me on this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActivationContext` is byte array that contains the ClickOnce deployment manifest for the application that is associated with this `ActivationContext`. It is used to get the ClickOnce deployment manifest for the current application.

if a ClickOnce application is running in the current `AppDomain` by checking the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ActivationContext` property.  If that value is non-null, then the domain is running a ClickOnce application.

This can be examined by Checking the "Enable ClickOnce security settings" in Project Properties "Security" tab

In the correct context ClickOnce security settings is disabled. Because it is not a click once deployment. So the context also will be null by default

Answer (score 1):

It's null by default if you don't specify an `ActivationContext`.

If you want an `ActivationContext`, use the `AppDomainSetup` constructor that takes an `ActivationContext` parameter.

Or the constructor that takes `ActivationArguments` which in turn has an `ActivationContext`.

Comment: Could you please help me on how to specify ActivationContext in AppDomainSetup() constructor?. I have tried to create an instance of ActivationContext and passed it to the AppDomainSetup constructor. But failed :(

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376620(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You are already passing an AppDomainSetup to the AppDomain constructor.  You need to pass an ActivationContext to the AppDomainSetup constructor.  I'm just rephrasing what I already said in the answer, isn't it clear?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to pass an ActivationContext instance into AppDomainSetup constructor not AppDomain constructor. It was a typo. Could you please share some snippet. So that it can be clear and very helpful to me  :)

Comment: The application is not clickonce. so the ActivationContext will be null.

Comment: So what's the problem?  It's normal that it should be null.